# The topology of the space of simple tensors

Tags: gn.general-topology

We identify the  vector  space tensor  product $\mathbb{R}^{m} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{n}$  with $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$

Let  $X$ be the  space  of  all  non zero simple tensors $X=\{a\otimes b \mid a\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{0\}, \;b\in \mathbb{R}^{m} \setminus \{0\}\}$.  Let $PX$  be  the  projectivization of  $X$, that is  $PX=\pi (X)$  where $\pi$ is  the  natural  quotient  map  from $\mathbb{R}^{(mn-1)} \setminus \{0\}$ to  $\mathbb{R}P^{mn-1}$.

What  can  be  said  about the  topology of  $X$ and  $PX$?Are they prime  topological spaces?What  can  be  said  about the  fixed point  property  of  $X$  and  $PX$.

A  prime  space is  a  space  which is  not  homeomorphic to  a  (nontrivial)  product  spaces.

Comment: $PX$ is the image of the Segre embedding of $\mathbf P^{n-1} \times \mathbf P^{m-1}$ into $\mathbf P^{mn-1}$.